# All the items are not taken in by the dictionary. Only the last item is taken in. How do I store all the values in the dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is the code:

```py
d = []
d1 = {}
print(type(d1))
desss = df['Description'].head()
for des in desss:
    print(des)
    d1['Description'] = des
    d.append(d1)
d
```

This is the output:

```
<class 'dict'>
Sr Project Manager \xe2\x80\x93 Cluster / Infotainment/ Automotive. Minimum 10 years experience in embedded domain \xe2\x80\x93 Automotive Cluster is preferred.
Knowledge of Automotive Domain - cluster and infotainment. In the area of Instrument Clusters and Infotainment Systems.
Strong Debugging Skills, Automotive infotainment Background Android framework and linux kernel. Porting of Applications across platforms,.
Ensure quality of delivery for customer releasesExcellent debugging and analytical skillsIndependent Cluster Infotainment Domain knowledge and handling skills\xe2\x80\xa6
Prior automotive experience in integrated instrument cluster applications, ADAS and self-driving systems preferred. 5 to 15 years of relevant experience.
[{'Description': 'Prior automotive experience in integrated instrument cluster applications, ADAS and self-driving systems preferred. 5 to 15 years of relevant experience.'},
 {'Description': 'Prior automotive experience in integrated instrument cluster applications, ADAS and self-driving systems preferred. 5 to 15 years of relevant experience.'},
 {'Description': 'Prior automotive experience in integrated instrument cluster applications, ADAS and self-driving systems preferred. 5 to 15 years of relevant experience.'},
 {'Description': 'Prior automotive experience in integrated instrument cluster applications, ADAS and self-driving systems preferred. 5 to 15 years of relevant experience.'},
 {'Description': 'Prior automotive experience in integrated instrument cluster applications, ADAS and self-driving systems preferred. 5 to 15 years of relevant experience.'}]
```

How can I rectify the above mistake?

Can someone help??

Comment: append a copy of the dictionary to the list  `d.append(d1.copy())`, otherwise you are adding references to the same dictionary  again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `d.append(d1)`, you actually only enqueue a pointer to `d1`. At the same time, when you run `d1['Description'] = des`, you change the description field of an existing object, you don't create a new object.

Therefore, you're changing the object after you've enqueued a reference to it, and because the list doesn't store a copy of the object, the value in the list is changed as well. The following alternative should work:

```py
d = []
desss = df['Description'].head()
for des in desss:
    print(des)
    d1 = {}
    d1['Description'] = des
    d.append(d1)
d
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to create a dictionary named `d1` and expect that it should contain all the elements that are found under `df['Description'].head()`. 
But the code below suggests that, you're trying to overwrite the already present contents of that dict.

```py
d1['Description'] = des
```

Thus, to **append** the new data to `d1` dict, your dict should probably look like

```py
d1 = {
'Description': [des1, des2, des2]
}
```

Try appending to the pre-existing list present in your `d1` dict as

```py
d = []
d1 = {'Description': []}
print(type(d1))
desss = df['Description'].head()
for des in desss:
    print(des)
    d1['Description'].append(des)
    #d.append(d1)
#d
print(d1) # Should print the whole d1 dict
```

This should solve your problem.